# generate mapping for index in logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have this log file whose values I would like to insert into elasticsearch though logstash. I want to write a .conf file for the same. If inserted as is, the date attribute which is in the form of "14/Nov/2014 08:56:23" is read as a string. I would like to format it such that it is read as a date. I would like to do changes only in the logstash .conf file. How do I go about it? Moreover, is it possible to set that date as the timestamp??

my config file file  looks something like this:

```
input {
    file {
    path => "/home/sagnik/NGINX\ LOGS/access.log.4"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}
filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    mutate { replace => { "type" => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

and my log is something like :

```
192.168.3.33 - - [14/Nov/2014:04:03:01 +0530] "GET /static/img/erecharge/datacard_2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 12892 "http://ph.kuchvi.com/agent?action1=TRSRC&country=JV&productType=MOBILE" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36" "203.111.224.53, 23.76.205.89"
```

I am getting the date, in string format

Comment: Can you share what filter are you using as well as the pattern and a sample log statement? will be helpful to debug and address your problem !

Comment: The only thing I see is that your regexp pattern should probably be written as: if [path] =~ /access/.